# how to create a multidimensional array with php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I want to create this array

```
Array (
    [1] => Array (
        [qual] => 1
        [race] => 3
        [finish] => 1
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [qual] => 2
        [race] => 1
        [finish] => 1
)
```

the number [1] and [2] is the driver id. This is how i get the data from the db

```
$raceUitslagArray = array();
$sqlRaceUitslag = mysql_query("SELECT uitslag.rijderId AS rijderId, combinatie.Chassis     AS chassis, combinatie.Motor AS motor, uitslag.qual AS qual, uitslag.race AS race, uitslag.finish AS finish
                FROM uitslag, combinatie
                    WHERE combinatie.Rijder = uitslag.rijderId && uitslag.raceId = '".$_POST['raceId']."'");
while($inhoudRaceUitslag = mysql_fetch_array($sqlRaceUitslag)) {
```

the data i need in the array is

```
$inhoudRaceUitslag['qual'] 
$inhoudRaceUitslag['race'] 
$inhoudRaceUitslag['finish'] 
$inhoudRaceUitslag['rijderId']
```

i think i should use **array_push($raceUitslagArray,$inhoudRaceUitslag['rijderId']);** but i can't figure it out how to get all the information in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier than you might think. `$inhoudRaceUitslag` is an (associative) array, as returned by mysql_fetch_array. You can simply add it associatively to the `$raceUitslagArray`, like this:

```
while($inhoudRaceUitslag = mysql_fetch_array($sqlRaceUitslag)) {
    $raceUitslagArray[$inhoudRaceUitslag['rijderId']] = $inhoudRaceUitslag;
}
```

This way you're using `$inhoudRaceUitslag['rijderId']` as the *key*, and the entire returned row (as stored in `$inhoudRaceUitslag`) as *value*.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$raceUitslagArray = array();
$sqlRaceUitslag = mysql_query("SELECT uitslag.rijderId AS rijderId, combinatie.Chassis AS chassis, combinatie.Motor AS motor,  uitslag.qual AS qual, uitslag.race AS race, uitslag.finish AS finish FROM uitslag, combinatie WHERE combinatie.Rijder = itslag.rijderId && uitslag.raceId = '".$_POST['raceId']."'");
$result = array();
$i = 1;
while($inhoudRaceUitslag = mysql_fetch_array($sqlRaceUitslag, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$result[$i++] = $inhoudRaceUitslag;
```

Comment: This has the same issue as feeela's answer - the keys of your array are defined iteratively rather than associatively.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I didn't read/understand your question enough

Answer (score -1):

The following line

```
while( $results[@$i++] = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {}
```

…would store your whole database result as an two dimensional array called `$results`.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php#110315

Comment: The question requires driver Id's as keys to the 2D array. Now you're just iterating.